# variables not working in my json call. keeps trying to open a file on my harddrive

Tags: javascript, json, variables, tumblr

> I've managed to figure out how to call my tumblr api and get back what
>   I need. It is working fine as long as I hard-code the address and the
>   other variables in the getJSON call.  The minute I try to use
>   variables in the call area, it tries to open a file on my harddrive or
>   it strips off the "http:" at the beginning of my url.
>
> What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
            SkipNbr = 0;
            GetNbr = 50;
            var a = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/";
            var bname = "[myblogname].tumblr.com";
            var c = "/posts/photo?api_key=";
            var MyAPIkey = "myAPIkey";
            var xx = "&limit="+GetNbr+"&offest="+SkipNbr+"?jsonp=?";

            var callstring = "'"+a+bname+c+MyAPIkey+xx+"'";

            console.log(callstring);
            $.getJSON(callstring, function (data) {
          //         $.getJSON("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/[myblogname].tumblr.com/posts/photo?api_key=[myAPIkey]&limit=GetNbr&offset=SkipNbr&jsonp=?", function (data) {
                    console.log(data.response.posts[0].caption);

                    $.each(data.response.posts, function (i, data) {
                        $("div").append(i+1 + " " + data.tags.toString() + "<br>");
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>


 <script type="text/javascript">
 function myFunction()
 {
 SkipNbr = 0;
  GetNbr = 50;
 $.getJSON("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/[myblogname].tumblr.com/posts/photo?api_key=   [myAPIkey]&limit=GetNbr&offset=SkipNbr&jsonp=?", function (data) {
 console.log(data.response.posts[0].caption);
 alert(data.response.posts[0].caption);
 $.each(data.response.posts, function (i, data) {
 $("div").append(i+1 + " " + data.tags.toString() + "<br>");
 });

 }
</script>




</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 //call after page loaded
 // window.onload=myfunction();
 </script>
<div></div>
</body>

 </html>
```

Comment: Is it because of the added apostrophe at the beginning and end of `callstring`? I think `callstring` will end up being "`'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/[myblogname].tumblr.com/posts/photo?api_key=myAPIkey&limit=GetNbr&offset=SkipNbr&jsonp=?'`" and this value will not work.  Try removing both of these: `"'"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this:

```
var callstring = "'"+a+bname+c+MyAPIkey+xx+"'";
```

should be this:

```
var callstring = a+bname+c+MyAPIkey+xx;
```

Comment: Awesome!  thank you.  it was that PLUS I needed a & and not a ? in from the front of the jsponp.   I'm not completely understanding this styntax but I'm guessing that the &s are for variables input into the api call and that ? are input variables into the getJSON call

var xx = "&limit="+GetNbr+"&offest="+SkipNbr+"&jsonp=?";